# Collinearity problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, statistical-significance

Consider a linear regression of this type: height: beta_0 + beta_1*weight.

Adding BMI as parameter would add complexity to the problem or just cause a collinearity problem?

Comment: BMI is proportional to weight so yes it would introduce collinearity

Comment: Ok, thank you. If I started from a simple linear beta_0+beta_1 and subsequently added the third parameter, how would the first two change?

Comment: This is pointless, $\text{BMI}=\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{height}^2} \cdot c$ (where c is some constant), there is no new information here, and you are adding y into your x's, which might be a problem later if you want to make predictions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes, we can suppose that BMI and weight are highly correlated. You can verify it by performing a correlation between BMI and weight and checking the resulting coefficient, but as in previous responses, they will correlate.
Accordingly, considering both in the same model could also heavily alter your outcomes (e.g. no predictor is significant). You should choose the most important for your research.

Comment: Thank you. Can we then state that the parameter will vary so as to result less valid? Also, what would happen to training and test error?

Comment: Yes, you could. 

Regarding training and test, I think it depends on the algorithm/method chosen.

To my knowledge collinearity is an issue with models based on linear relationships, so linear or logistic regressions may be affected. In other algorithms, for example, in decision trees, collinearity should not be an issue, but you have two "equal" variables which is rarely a good choice.

Comment: What about a Lasso regression?

Comment: Also, does x_3 adds complexity to the model?

Comment: I don't know if Lasso regression clearly solves collinearity issues. 
I link you the best reference I have found, which indicates that Lasso doesn't seem the best solution to solve multicollinearity as it reports:
"if the correction of multicollinearity is your goal, then Lasso isn’t the way to go." and it seems that Lasso will choose only 1 of the correlated variable. I suggest you the reference as it also talks about ridge regression and elastic net which maybe could help you.  

x_3 adds complexity if the definition of complexity comprehends the "number of parameters".